# Simple forms authenticated website does not redirect after login

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have a website built on a simple authentication model. It runs fine locally and on local IIS, but it is not redirecting to the default page after typing in the correct credentials, all this in the test server.

The code goes as follows.

*Web.config*

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="50000" />
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="exc/exc.aspx?e=1">
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="exc/404.aspx?e=404"/>
        </customErrors>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="admin/login.aspx" defaultUrl="admin/main.aspx" />
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <location path="admin">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="admin/css/cms.css">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="admin/css/styles.css">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="admin/images">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="exc/exc.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

*login.aspx*

> The form action property is blank and AutoEventWireup is true.

*login.aspx.cs*

```
protected void btnAuth_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //Some code not shown...

        //User Validation
            ValidateUserResponse response = new ValidateUserResponse();
            response = service.ValidateUser(request);

            if (response.State == true)
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(request.Alias, False);            
}
```

*SignOut*

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);            
}
```

On the test server the URL looks something like this:

```
http://192.168.1.58/TestSite/admin/login.aspx
```

On VS2010 works well as well on my local IIS once published, but don't understand why isn't redirecting to the default page after the login when published on the TestServer. Showing that the *website requires to log in and a 403 forbidden error*.

Locally I have tested it with both URL forms and works (the virtual folder name is different):

```
http://192.168.1.58/TestSite1/admin/login.aspx

http://localhost/TestSite1/admin/login.aspx
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions on the matter to make it work.

Thank you.

**----------Update-----------**

I solved the problem this way:

1. Right Click on the Virtual Directory containing the WebApp
2. Go to the Directory Security Tab
3. Click on Modify
4. Unchecked Integrated Windows Authentication
5. Anonymous Access has to be checked as well

This made the WebForms Authentication settings on Web.Config to start having effect on the WebApp.

Thank you.

Comment: "it doesn't allow to login on a test server." and "why isn't redirecting on the TestServer." What do you mean? What is the actual problem?

Comment: Thanks Mike. I've made some edits that expect clarify the problem.

Comment: Ok, it is more clear now. So what happens when they login? Where do they end up if not your default page?

Comment: Another update has been made, check it out please.

Comment: Do you have forms authentication enabled in IIS on the web server?

Comment: Hi Joe, I'll ask the customer's IT people and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: @Joe Enos  I think that forms authentication is enabled tho haven't looked deeply into it yet till Monday, because the last time I was there I was able to run the login page of the site and got a blank 403 error page everytime I logged in successfully. If I disable anonymous authentication on my local machine (and with that forms authentication in my understanding), such page access is denied by IIS so I am assuming it's on. Aside from that do you thing anything else happening?. Thank you.

Comment: @CoderRoller That's all I can think of - based on what you're describing, it really has to be configuration, so either web.config, applicationHost.config, machine.config, or something inside IIS. Never fun trying to track this kind of stuff down. I always hate the [works on my machine](http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0128776ff992970c-pi) problems.

Comment: @JoeEnos Hi Joe, I've got it solved thanks to your suggestion. Please post it as and an answer so I can mark it and you can get points retribution out of it. Thank you.

Comment: @CoderRoller Awesome, glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure forms authentication is enabled in IIS on the web server.