# Forms Authentication with IIS 7.5 - Not Authorized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, forms-authentication

I have a Web application deployed to Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5.  The application is ASP.NET MVC 3 with .Net Framework 4.0.

Authentication Settings:  Anonymous and Forms Authentication is enabled.  I've set the Anonymous user identity value under the Anonymous properties to point to "Application pool Identity" instead of a specific user.

Web.Config

When trying to remotely access the application from my machine, I get the message "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials." when accessing the "Account/Logon" page.

I have no problems accessing the app on my local machine through visual studio.  I can also access the app on the Windows 2008 Server without any issues.  Only when I try to access the app on the server from my local machine do I get the problem.

Any ideas?

Some additional Notes:
- It's failing before I get to the login screen.

Comment: I had a similar problem somedays ago, see if it helps you. Also reset the default anonymous configuration for IUSR_YourPC.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030515/simple-forms-authenticated-website-does-not-redirect-after-login

Comment: How to you determine if the server allows Forms Authentication.

Comment: Right Click on the Virtual Directory containing the WebApp then:
-Go to the Directory Security Tab
-Click on Modify
-Unchecked Integrated Windows Authentication
-Anonymous Access has to be checked as well.

This how it looks like on the IIS6 GUI(Spanish):
http://s7.postimage.org/m95dx2zxn/form_Auth_Setts.jpg

Also check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447728/formsauthentication-loginurl

Comment: It's a little different on IIS7.  Forms and Anonymous is enabled.  Windows Auth is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

*I've set the Anonymous user identity value under the Anonymous properties to point to "Application pool Identity" instead of a specific user.*
Try setting it back to original `IUSR` and make sure `IUSR_YourComputerName` user has access to site's files/folder

Comment: I changed it back to IUSR and added IUSR to the folder permissions but still no luck.

Comment: What authentication scheme is set in your web.config?

Comment: Forms Authentication:<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>

Answer (score -2):

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c9239a89-fbee-4adc-b72f-7a6a9648331f/401-unauthorized-access-is-denied-due-to-invalid-credentials

Quoting from that article:

> IIS 7 was difficult for figuring out why i was getting the 401 -
>   Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials... until i
>   did this...
>
> 1.) Open iis and select the website that is causing the 401
>
> 2.) Open the "Authentication" property under the "IIS" header
>
> 3.) Click the "Windows Authentication" item and click "Providers"
>
> 4.) For me the issue was that Negotiate was above NTLM. I assume that there was some kind of handshake going on behind the scenes, but i was
>   never really authenticated. I moved the NTLM to the top most spot, and
>   BAM that fixed it.

Comment: The question is about Forms authentication, not Windows authentication